# SQL Server adding a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I add a variable in SQL Server to replace `%MV_AUG2019.json%` so that I only have to change it in one spot for all of those tables?

```
delete from [addresses] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [disabilities] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [MD] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [messages] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [MH] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [MV] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [permits] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [PP] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [registrationOwners] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
delete from [stops] where [uniqueFilename] like '%MV_AUG2019.json%'
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a variable in the following:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(1000) = 'name.json' -- provide file name here

delete from [addresses] where [uniqueFilename] like '%' + @var + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

I bet you are simply after -->

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(500) = 'MV_AUG2019.json'

delete from [addresses] where [uniqueFilename] like '%'+@FileName+'%'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doubling up the wildcards (`'%'`) by concatenating them to a variable which already contains them?

Comment: Doh!, The op said filename, I assumed that was part of the filename, updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can generate tables in dynamic

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(500) = 'MV_AUG2019.json'

SELECT 'DELETE FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +' WHERE '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+ ' LIKE '+'''%'+ @FileName+'%'''
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='uniqueFilename' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nvarchar','varchar')
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.